# prevent page break within \item in latex document

Tags: latex, page-break

I have a long document consisting of an enumeration. Each item consists of several lines, and possibly also includes other elements such as graphics and lists. The document type requires that each of these items appears on a single page, with no page break within item. Unused white space at the bottom of the page is acceptable.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \blindtext
  \item \blindtext % don't break this apart
  \item very long text here 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I know of solutions with the `samepage` environment, and also with `minipage`. The problem is that I can't wrap the individual `\item`s into these environments, which I would need.

`needspace` works, but then I need to determine the vertical extent of each item manually (at least that is what I think).

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate in the TeX stackechange site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution in the end? Would you mind sharing it? I am also looking for something that will stop a paragraph of an item in an `itemize` list from breaking over pages. `samepage` doesn't seem to work, and `minipage` is not suitable as it places foot-marks to the paragraph at the end of the item. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did in the end is use the enumitem package and break up the enumeration into parts which are in minipages:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}           % modified itemize

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[series=task,start=1,leftmargin=*,resume]
  \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume*=task]
     \item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer something less complicated, but at least it worked without manual pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a `\clearpage` with each `\item` via the following automation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\oldenumerate\enumerate% Store \begin{enumerate} in \begin{oldenumerate}
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate% Store \end{enumerate} in \end{oldenumerate}
\renewenvironment{enumerate}
  {\let\olditem\item% Store \item in \olditem
   \renewcommand{\item}{\clearpage\olditem}% Update \item
   \oldenumerate}% \begin{enumerate}
  {\endoldenumerate}% \end{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \blindtext
  \item \blindtext % don't break this apart
  \item very long text here 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above code updates the `enumerate` environment in a way that changes the `\item` code to be equivalent to `\clearpage\item` instead. This ensures that each `\item` will start on a new page, possibly leaving blank space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: resizing the margins of the `enumerate` environment so that the text does not get broken out of place.

Here is one answer on how to do this kind of manipulations on itemize environments: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170525/itemize-left-margin

Comment: This misses the point. I of course can hand-tune the document. However, there is a large number of such items, and I'd like to define blocks that get wrapped around as an intact entity, including the leading \item line.